# Setting an instance variable in initialize

Tags: objective-c, initialization

Is it possible to assign a value to an instance variable during an initialize class method?

I'm declaring a number of arrays, then creating an array of arrays, then assigning it to self.months, which is an instance variable.   Why does this not work, and how can I accomplish this?

```
      +(void)initialize
 {
    // .....
        NSArray *matrix = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec, nil ];

    self.months = matrix;
    [matrix release]
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set instance variables in class methods as you have no reference to an instance. The `initialize` method on a class is called the first time that class receives any messages and is meant to do any kind of global set-up that your class might need before any actual messages are processed. For example, setting up initial user defaults is typically done in the `initialize` method of your application's controller or delegate class.

To set up instance variables, you should do this in the object's designated initializer (this is `init` by default, but certain objects change the designated initializer if they need to take parameters). For example:

```
- (id)init {
  if( (self = [super init]) ) {
    myInstanceVariable = (int *)malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
  }
}

- (void)dealloc {
  free(myInstanceVariable);
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Here you actually have a reference to `self` which you can use because a distinct instance of an object has been allocated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused about what `initialize` does. It's to initialize **the class itself**. There is no instance, and thus there are no instance variables. To initialize an instance, override the `init` method.